# Doctrine left joins but wont get the fields of 2nd table, why?

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

for example, I have this:

```
$this->createQueryBuilder('x')->select()->join('x.coupons', 'c')->getQuery()->getResult()
```

there are `user`-s and their `coupon`-s. This do joins the `coupons` table but wont select its fields. If I refer to `->getCoupons()`, it will make an other select. Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: ```$this->createQueryBuilder('x')->select(['x', 'c'])->join('x.coupons', 'c')->getQuery()->getResult()```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your query builder to this:

```
$this->createQueryBuilder('x')
    ->select('x', 'c')
    ->join('x.coupons', 'c')
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult()
```